# Instagram and FB linking

Tags: instagram

Me and a colleague are using a business instagram account together so we can both have access and upload stuff.. but when we try to invite friends/follow it only comes up with "my personal profile friends" and not any of my colleagues? the insta accounts linked to our company's FB page..? so should have both of our fb account detail, ie friends and stuff??

Sorry I am not a developer :D and dont really have a clue if this is possible or if there is a way of doing it.

Thnks

Comment: Have you tried asking their support first?

Comment: Hey, there is not a way of getting directly speaking to a support team.. i can only find a "help centre" page and filter through frequently asked questions..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the forum for this, I would advise confirming things with instagram; Email support@instagram.com. Or report it on the app:

You can provide feedback or report a technical issue by clicking on the Options (gear wheel) in your profile and then tapping Report a Problem in the menu.

Anyways, from what I gather, even though the account is a business account, you must've been the one who created it and linked your facebook account. Even though its linked to your page, it's still only linked to your account, not your colleague's. Even if he is an admin on the facebook page.

With a little more research I found this:

https://www.facebook.com/help/218638451837962

There are more links on this that help with every part. I'm not completely clear on all the details. But everything here should work, again if none of this fixes your problem, confirm with instagram whether what you want is possible at all.

Comment: apologies.. someone suggested the page to me. thank you i will have a look and see what i can find :)